# Normal vector to a complex variable curve

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have a curve in the complex plane which has the form
$$z=f(\theta)=R(\theta)e^{i\theta},$$
where $R(\theta)$ is a real valued function.

I need an expression for the normal vector to this curve depending on $\theta$. Preferably in terms of $R(\theta)$ and $R'(\theta)$.

I understand that it have relationship with gradients and I try to use polar coordinates but I got stuck with the notation and my lack of knowledge. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm confused about what you understand as the normal vector of a complex curve. I'll try to give an answer, and hopefully someone else can correct me.

As I understand, your curve has the form $R(\theta)\cos(\theta) + iR(\theta)\sin(\theta)$ with parameter $\theta$. This curve can be though as parametrized curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
\vec{r}(\theta) = [ R(\theta)\cos(\theta),R(\theta)\sin(\theta)]
$$
Note that you only have one parameter $\theta$, and thus you can compute a tangent vector of $\vec{r}(\theta)$ differentiating along $\theta$ only:
$$
\vec{r}'(\theta) = [ R'(\theta)\cos(\theta) -R(\theta)\sin(\theta) , R'(\theta)\sin(\theta) + R(\theta)\cos(\theta) ]
$$
and construct a normal vector just by switching the components and changing the sign of one of them:
$$
\vec{n}(\theta) = [-R'(\theta)\sin(\theta) - R(\theta)\cos(\theta),R'(\theta)\cos(\theta)-R(\theta)\sin(\theta)]
$$
You can check that $\vec{r}\cdot \vec{n} = 0$. From here, you may want to normalize this vector, and convert it to a complex number form.

Note that this was equivalent to computing
$$
\vec{n}(\theta) \sim i f'(\theta)
$$
this is: $f'(\theta)$ is already a tangent vector and you multiply by $i = e^{i\pi/2}$ (90 degree rotation) to obtain an orthogonal vector to the tangent one (precisely the normal vector).

Is this kind of what you where looking for?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks